# Trouble running docker registry in insecure mode on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-registry, insecure-connection

I'm trying to run a docker registry in insecure mode on ubuntu 16.04 (docker  v1.12.3).  I made the changes specified in [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/).

/etc/default/docker:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 10.10.10.10:5000"
```

and then restarted the docker service.  However I'm having no luck. When I try to connect I get

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://10.10.10.10:5000/v1/_ping: 
http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this [docker/distribution issue](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874#issuecomment-237194314) could help (when used with docker 1.12):

> - Create or modify `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
    { "insecure-registries":["myregistry.example.com:5000"] }
```

> - Restart docker daemon

```
    sudo service docker restart
```

On Unbuntu 16.04, check also if [configuring docker through systemd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/) is better.